# Can anybody recommend a slider a horizontal slider or carousel with variable image width support and touch support?

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

It seems like this is impossible to do! But I have seen some examples like this one

http://francksauvaire.com/project/962

Does anybody know a similar plugin? It would help so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly recommend Swiper.

```
http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/
```

Check out their multi-width demo down on this page - the demo is titled 'Different Widths'

```
http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/demos.php
```

This slider works beautifully on touch devices and has an awesome API!

Answer (score 0):

What about jQuery Image Slider. It supports touch, swipe and it is responsive.

[Link](http://www.jssor.com/)